# molokai in vim error when opening files

Tags: ubuntu, vim, plugins

I have struggle the installation of vim color schemes for long time, I follow the steps of the following to do the installation

https://github.com/tomasr/molokai

And find out that the color scheme does not work as it is (with the error shown in the capture below), is there any steps I have ran wrong? Appreciate for the great help

p.s.:
1) System: using Ubuntu 11.10

2) Access via putty in windows and Ubuntu vim also not work

3) Error shown

[image: Error shown]

[image]

4) .vimrc file

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to edit? (Also we can't tell you what steps you did wrong if you don't list them) And how are you generating the E488 errors? Nothing in your vimrc seems to suggest that. Colorschemes don't normally cause those errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am trying to edit .php, .css ,.py files

The following are the steps I am following,
1) Download and copy the molokai.vim to ~/.vim/colors folder
2) Copy and paste the following to ~/.vimrc file
let g:molokai_original = 1
let g:rehash256 = 1

3) Add colorscheme molokai to .vimrc file.
4) Use the vim to edit the web files like .php, .css etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error messages, it looks like Vim is sourcing an HTML file. You may have saved [the marked-up page](https://github.com/tomasr/molokai/blob/master/colors/molokai.vim) from GitHub instead of the [raw text file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tomasr/molokai/master/colors/molokai.vim).

Also, if you want to override the colorscheme's `Search` highlighting, you need to put the `:hi Search` command **after** the `:colorscheme` command in your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: @romainl Good to have all of you around here. No Vim question goes unanswered!